# Remove value from List of String does not throw ConcurrentModificationException. Why?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

```
public class ListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
        strList.add("A");
        strList.add("B");
        strList.add("C");
          for (String str : strList) {
            if (str.equals("B")) {
                strList.remove(str);  // Work fine, does not throw ConcurrentModificationException
            }
        }
```

In case 2

```
    //Creating an object of List Object
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(6);

        for (Integer elem : list) {
            if (elem.equals(4)) {
                list.remove(elem); // throw ConcurrentModificationException
            }
        }
```

In case 3

```
      List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("A");
        stringList.add("B");
        stringList.add("B");
        stringList.add("B");
        stringList.add("C");

        for (String str : stringList) {
            if (str.equals("B")) {
                stringList.remove(str);  // throw ConcurrentModificationException
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You're incorrectly assuming that it *must* throw an exception, it doesn't, it will throw an exception if it detects the modification, which it does on a best-effort basis. Especially when modifying the second-last item from a list _if_ the iterator is also at the second-last, the modification isn't always detected, IIRC, and removing the last item _if_ the iterator is also at the last item is usually not detected. Also, contrary to the placement of the comment, the `remove` will not throw the exception, the iteration in the for-each will do that.